# What are the limitations of masm assembler when writing system software

Tags: assembly, operating-system

What are the limitations of MASM assembler when writing a system software like operating systems? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps you should explain what you mean "limitations".

Comment: Since it belongs to MS, can we create another os using it.

Comment: The _main_ limitation is the lack of the `make_os` macro which would allow me to crank out an OS while I nicked off down the beach for the day :-)

Comment: Sir,I can't understand.can u elaborate please..

Comment: masm is still around?  I thought it went the way of tasm.  I'd go with http://www.nasm.us/ (nasm)....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I for one would not want to write an Operating System using MASM.
From the license we learn:

*What you CANNOT do with the MASM32 Project.*

1. The MASM32 Project is not an item of trade or commerce. It cannot be either purchased or sold.
2. The MASM32 Project cannot be re-licenced or made subordinate to any other form of licence.
3. None of its components or source code are redistributable.
4. **You cannot use the MASM32 Project to write software for Non-Microsoft Operating Systems.**
5. You cannot use the MASM32 Project to write any form of illegal software.
6. The project does not authorise the use of the Microsoft Trademark in your software or claims that your software is certified by Microsoft.

*Who can use the MASM32 Project ?*

The licence extends to any private individual, organisation, educational institution, Government Department and any Company and/or Corporation for their personal/internal use and **it can be used to develop and distribute or sell software for the Windows Operating System.**

*Why is the MASM32 Project licenced in this manner ?*

The MASM32 Project is true freeware written by programmers for programmers so that they can **realise the full power of the Windows Operating System** without being subject to any additional conditions or external interests. The project has been designed as enabling technology to extend the capacity and range of programmers interested in **learning and writing Microsoft assembler for Microsoft Operating Systems**.

*Exclusion of open source projects and software.*

The MASM32 project cannot be used to create open source software or any other project under any form of licence that requires the user of the MASM32 project to surrender the rights they are afforded under the MASM32 licence. In particular the MASM32 licence completely **excludes projects licenced under the GNU organisation's published GPL licence and/or variants**.

Comment: 'Writiing software for non-Microsoft operating systems' isn't the same as writing a non-Microsoft operating system.

Comment: The language is difficult to interpret, but if I were to guess, a non-Microsoft OS counts as software for non-Microsoft OS.

Answer (score 3):

None if you don't count the time it would take to write it.

Comment: Can a os be created using it?

Comment: Yes, you can write any program with it including operating systems. You need a license for Visual Studio to execute the MASM but not for the code it produces.

Comment: @BijuRakhul  - yes an os can be created using masm (or ml.exe). I've worked at companies that used masm or ml to create operating systems for X86 processors used in embedded systems.

Answer (score 1):

1. Taking into account your other questions I'd recommend you to download and browse through (a few times) the [Combined Volume Set of Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) as it **defines** the dictionary of the assembly language and what the assembly language is about (unless you want to target `RISC` processors like [ARM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture) where the instruction set and the assembly language are quite different)
2. When choosing your assembler then some things to consider:

   - avoid [vendor lock-in](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vendor_lock-in) so that 10 years after you write the code you don't have to throw the code away or rewrite it completely because the assembler vendor closed it's business ("*cross platform*" and "*open source*" seems to be the magic words here)
   - is there an IDE with code navigation and refactoring support available for this language?
   - are there any ready-to-reuse libraries available for the language?
   - is the language's syntax easy to read/write or it's just a mess of hard to read and decipher symbols?
   - is there any considerable programmer community ready to help?
3. There are complete working Operating Systems written in assembly language which could server as examples.

   [MenuetOS](http://www.menuetos.net/) is almost entirely written with port of Tomasz Grysztar's [Flat Assembler (FASM)](http://flatassembler.net/docs.php)

---

Suitability of [MASM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Macro_Assembler) for your needs depends on your goals.

It has friendly syntax, there are some IDEs and due to its age there may be quite a bit of ready-to-reuse code available (written decades ago) but you will never be able to extend it by yourself and you won't be able to port it to another platform because it's closed source and in the community of assembly language fighters there won't be many of you.

If you're just learning then go pick any language and tool you have available and start coding.